# The number of optical isomers of 3,4-dichlorobutan-2-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, chirality, optical-properties

The number of optical isomers possible for the given organic molecule is?
$\ce{CH_3-C^*H(OH)-CHCl-CH_2Cl}$ (the configuration is fixed at $\ce{C^*}$)

The given answer is 2.
The carbon marked with an asterisk is chiral, and the carbon to the right of it is also chiral. Doesn't that give 4 isomers? What does "configuration is fixed" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carbon marked with the asterisk cannot change its configuration, for it to be counted as a stereocentre, it must be able to. hence 2 isomers only

Comment: So we're considering the optical rotation of the carbon which lies next to the one marked with an asterisk?

Comment: Yes. The only chiral atom here is the third C, which is part of the CHCl group.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i meant